# Can somebody explain how to make vscode the default editor on osx?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

Xcode is the current default editor when opening files and I'd like to switch it to vscode

Answer (score 115, accepted):

The editor is associated with the file extension on macOS.

When you select one of your code files press *Command+I* to open the inspector (or choose "Get Info" from either the "File"- or contextual menu) and you will find a section called "Open With:". When expanded you should see a drop-down menu and a "Change All…" button.

Pick the application you would like to open this file from the drop-down menu and then click on "Change All…". A dialog will ask you to confirm that your chosen editor shall be used for all files that have the same extension as the current one.

Do this for all file-types where you would like to change the associated editor.

Comment: After you do this for a few different file extensions, you'll notice it changes it for the others as well.

Comment: What about files without extensions?  This suggestion causes an error for files without extensions.

Comment: This works for most of the file extensions but I find it really weird and there has to be a more exhaustive way to change this built into the OS

Comment: A script that did this for the most common filetype would be lovely.

Comment: This works, but how do we do it without the GUI? Can I put something in my .zshrc file perhaps?

Comment: See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/123834/288931) on how to set VSCode as default application for all files with mimetype text/plain (replace `com.sublimetext.3` with `com.microsoft.vscode`)

Comment: See Tommy Neeld answer for way to make VS Code default for all file types on mac m1 https://stackoverflow.com/a/70402997/11331763

Answer (score 40):

I used a combination of [Thomas Krajacic's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43665710/11852581) answer above and a tool called [duti](https://github.com/moretension/duti) - making the vscode the default editor for all these languages known to GitHub [languages.yml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/linguist/master/lib/linguist/languages.yml)

```
brew install duti python-yq
curl "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/linguist/master/lib/linguist/languages.yml" \
  | yq -r "to_entries | (map(.value.extensions) | flatten) - [null] | unique | .[]" \
  | xargs -L 1 -I "{}" duti -s com.microsoft.VSCode {} all



# Use duti to set defaults for specific files to VSCode
duti -s com.microsoft.VSCode public.plain-text all
duti -s com.microsoft.VSCode public.source-code all
duti -s com.microsoft.VSCode public.data all
duti -s com.microsoft.VSCode .css all
duti -s com.microsoft.VSCode .gitattributes all
duti -s com.microsoft.VSCode .gitignore all
duti -s com.microsoft.VSCode .htaccess all
duti -s com.microsoft.VSCode .js all
duti -s com.microsoft.VSCode .json all
duti -s com.microsoft.VSCode .link all
duti -s com.microsoft.VSCode .md all
duti -s com.microsoft.VSCode .mv all
duti -s com.microsoft.VSCode .mvt all
duti -s com.microsoft.VSCode .scss all
duti -s com.microsoft.VSCode .sh all
duti -s com.microsoft.VSCode .txt all
duti -s com.microsoft.VSCode .xml all
duti -s com.microsoft.VSCode .yaml all
duti -s com.microsoft.VSCode .zsh all
```

Also linking to [another thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/123833/replace-text-edit-as-the-default-text-editor/123834#123834) discussing the same and [this site](https://alexpeattie.com/blog/associate-source-code-files-with-editor-in-macos-using-duti/).

FYI I am running Monterey 12 on Mac M1

Comment: bless you for this!