# Default IDE for terminal mac - (react app)

Tags: reactjs, macos, terminal, visual-studio-code, ide

I am debugging a react app. If I click on this link given by the terminal, IDE Atom is Opening. How can I change it to another IDE like VS code for example?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use VS code integrated terminal?

Comment: You need to change your default IDE... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43665346/can-somebody-explain-how-to-make-vscode-the-default-editor-on-osx

Answer (score 2):

Atom and VScode are text editors. If you go to the file SingleVariation.js from the link and right click on it you can select get info. This opens the get info window shown below.

[image: Get_info window]

About halfway down the window is a section designated as "Open With". This determines which application will open a file. The menu in that section may show Fetch. That just means it's looking for apps that could be used to open that file. When the search is finished you can pull down that menu and set it to VScode. After that click the button that says "change all". Now whenever you double-click on a .js file, it will open in VScode.